# project point to line-segment on sphere

Tags: c#, math, geometry, geospatial

I have a line-segment defined by two points (L<sub>1</sub>, L<sub>2</sub>) on a sphere and a third point (P) on a sphere. I want to find the projection P' of P on the line-segment (L<sub>1</sub>, L<sub>2</sub>).

[image: projection]

I solved this problem on the plane but need help for this spherical version.

Ideal would be a C#-snipped like I have for the 2D-Version:

```
private Coordinate ProjectOnEdge(Coordinate L1, Coordinate L2, Coordinate P) { // ... }
```

A bit more formal:
I want the intersection point of the great circle that passes P and is perpendicular to the great circle through L1 and L2.

Comment: There's no canonical projection from the sphere to the line segment (there is no "*the* projection). You'll need to be more specific about what map you want from the sphere to the segment.

Comment: I want the intersection point of the great circle that passes P and is perpendicular to the great circle through L1 and L2.

Comment: What coordinate system are you using?

Comment: Spherical coordinates (as approximation to WGS84)

Answer (score 0):

You can combine formulas from [latlong page](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html), working in spherical coordinates:

Get cross-track angular distance

```
 δxt = asin( sin(δ13) ⋅ sin(θ13−θ12) )
```

Use it to get along-track angular distance

```
 δat = acos( cos(δ13) / cos(δxt) )
```

Calculate bearing from the start point ti the end point

```
θ = atan2( sin Δλ ⋅ cos φ2 , cos φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 − sin φ1 ⋅ cos φ2 ⋅ cos Δλ )
```

And finally calculate coordinates using "Destination point given distance and bearing from start point" approach:

```
φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ )
λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )
```

Two last steps might be changed into "Intermediate point" approach